# Get dynamic input from user

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a simple project, an Inventory management system.

We have a set of items for sale in our inventory (defined in the database) and we dispatch items in the quantity that the customer order.

The issue I have is, a user may order just 1 item, or they may order a 100 items, in whatever quantities they prefer (assume the user of this system gets this info through an email).

So I have some trouble creating the "Sales Order" GUI.

I tried using a ListBox / ListView. There I can select all the items they want and generate a sales order, but I can't enter the corresponding quantity.

It is not practical to have like 20 text boxes in the form.

Comment: Let users select **one** item from the List, for which a user must specify a quantity (use a NumercUpDown for this, not a TextBox). Use a "Add to Cart" Button, to store the item along with the quantity (show both in a another ListView and add means to remove an Item. Another Button would do). The users can repeat this operation for as many items as they like. Use a "Send Order" Button to complete the *purchase*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems as if a good approach would be to have a means of selecting the specific product you want to quantify first. Supermarket POS systems do this through PLU (Price Look Up) codes that identify the product name and price. You could alternately have a search box that combs through your database for product names matching the search query.

After that you can have one text box (I would recommend a [number spinner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=netframework-4.8)) to select the quantity.

Finally have a button that submits that order of that specific product and move on to the next. You could wait to submit all the quantities needed until the order is completed to signify that it is one unique order if that information is important to you.